# Get EventStream from a node with React and Bacon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frp, bacon.js

This is how I can get an EventStream from a regular DOM node with bacon.js:

```
var el = document.getElementById('input1');
var stream = Bacon.fromEvent(el, 'input')
```

When using React, DOM nodes may be recreated after some render() iteration, so obtaining events from real DOM nodes (with React.findDOMNode) is not an option. The only option I can think of for now is to handle events manually and then push them to buses:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
  streams: {},
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.streams.inputBus = new Bacon.Bus();
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.streams.inputBus.end();
  },
  onInput: function(e) {
    this.streams.inputBus.push(e);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <input type="text" onInput={this.onInput} />
    );
  }
});
```

Is this approach ok, or are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that it is OK. Similar approaches are used in these two examples:

- https://github.com/niklasvh/react-bacon-flux-poc
- https://github.com/milankinen/react-bacon-todomvc